# static equivalent in Android for kotlin to avoid handler memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, kotlin, handler

When I've used handlers in Android before using java I would get an Android Studio lint message saying that I should use a static handler, otherwise memory leaks will occur.  Since Kotlin has no static keyword, how should I handle it?  Here is my class:

```
class TaskDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private val handlerComment = MyOptionMenuBarHandler(this)

   private fun setUpToolBar() { 
        handlerComment.sendEmptyMessage(0)
   }

   private class MyOptionMenuBarHandler(activity: TaskDetailActivity) : Handler() {

       private val activity: WeakReference<TaskDetailActivity> = WeakReference<TaskDetailActivity>(activity)

       override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        //do the work
        .....
       }

   }
}
```

Is there anything special I need to do to avoid memory leaks using Kotlin?

Comment: have you tried companion object yet?

Comment: I thought about that, would that do it?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any better approach. Actually I am new in Kotlin too and still learning. Usually if I want to create a static variable/method in Kotlin and can be accessed both in Java and Kotlin, i would use companion object with **@JvmStatic** annotation for the variable/method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lint tells you to mark your inner `Handler` class as `static` to prevent compiler from adding the reference of enclosing class into the `Handler` implementation (it adds it by default to all inner non-static classes), because this might create a memory leak.

Now, Kotlin has notions between `inner` and `nested` class. The `nested` class is what you get by default if you declare some class `Foo` inside another class. The nested classes do not have the implicit reference to enclosing class (they're similar to the Java's inner static classes in that regard). Your `MyOptionMenuBarHandler` class is exactly that.

If you want to add the reference to enclosing class to your inner class, you can mark it as `inner`.

**In short**:

1. Kotlin and Java have different defaults in regard to inner class. In Kotlin the inner class does not have reference to enclosing class by default, in java it does.
2. If you want to have implicit reference to outer class in Kotlin, mark inner class as `inner`.
3. If you don't want to have such reference in Java, mark inner class as `static`.

Comment: So I'm not sure.  Should I mark the class as inner or nested?

Comment: You don't need to mark it at all. By default the class declared inside another class is considered `nested`, i.e. does not have the implicit reference to outer class, i.e. can not create memory leak in a way described by Lint.